# Confusion about definition of linear equation re: Lorenz system & algebraic equations

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, nonlinear-system

I am confused about the definition of a linear equation.

First, why is the Lorenz system considered to contain three nonlinear equations? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system#Overview) They all look linear to me. I don't see any powers on any of the terms in *any* of the 3 equations (much less *all* of them).

Second, I just realized the obvious fact that any linear equation can become nonlinear by simply multiplying both sides by the variable (e.g., $y=x$ can become $xy=x^2$). So how can we make a distinction between linear and nonlinear equations?

(I am a high school Calculus student, by the way - we haven't gone anywhere remotely close to the Lorenz equations in class but I'm interested in them.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terms $xz$ and $xy$ in the second and third equation make the system nonlinear.

You are right that you can transform any linear equation to a nonlinear one (the opposite is not always true though). But be careful: The way you did it, the two equations are not equivalent. For the second equation $x=0$ is a solution regardless of the value of $y$.

Answer (score 1):

The distinction is simple:

In a linear equation, the operations performed are no more than *multiplication of variables by numbers alone,* and *addition of such products.*

Anything other than this is nonlinear.